Flutter for IOS Error: Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
I am developing a flutter app using these modules:
font_awesome_flutter
google_maps_flutter
http
flutter_typeahead
google_maps_flutter_web
permission_handler
google_sign_in
flutter_stripe
flutter_dotenv
url_launcher
recase
intl
awesome_notifications
workmanager
hive
hive_flutter
hive_generator
flutter_lints
flutter_svg
flutter_launcher_icons
build_runner

There is no issue with android but when I run on IOS I get this error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
#0      PathProviderApi.getDirectoryPath (package:path_provider_foundation/messages.g.dart:40:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:121:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      HiveX.initFlutter (package:hive_flutter/src/hive_extensions.dart:12:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      main (package:projectName/main.dart:22:3)
<asynchronous suspension>

I have tried to delete and recreate the ios folder reinstalled cocoapod and pod install I have run flutter clean and flutter pub get but to no avail
